# Where can I find "user tags" in texstudio?

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

In the [features](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) of TeXstudio they indicate the ability to use "tags". If you google for "user tags texstudio", you also find a blog defining user tags in TeXstudio. Basically, because I wanted to quickly replace some frequent text that I use. E.g. replacing `h2o2` by `\ce{H2O2}`.

I had implemented this in the user tags of TeXmaker, but I cannot find a similar menu in TeXstudio.

### Screenshot of TeXstudio

[image: screenshot]

Yet, in TeXmaker (similar build to TeXstudio from what I hear), you can easily find the user tags.

### Screenshot of TeXmaker

[image]

### My questions are:

1. Where can I define the user tags in TeXStudio?
2. I am guessing TeXstudio may not have this feature. Is there any other way for me to quickly replace text that I type often as in the given example above?

Comment: @JohnWickerson thanks for the tip. I am quite new with Latex in general and hadn't thought about using a macro. Indeed, that probably solves my problem without using a "user tag".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In TeXstudio, the concept of `Macros` is a generalized form of User Tags:
[image]

User Tags are eqivilent to a 'Normal' Macro without a trigger:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand the point of text-replacement. You save a couple of keystrokes the first time you type it, but it doesn't help at all when you come back to edit your code, or read over it again. And these latter two activities happen much more often.

Anyway, I suggest simply defining a macro, like this:

```
\newcommand\hooh{\ce{H2O2}}
```

Comment: Though this does not exactly answer the question about user tags, it solves the problem that was making me ask about them in the first place. Thanks for the help!